# how to make jquery show 1 data first then load 1 more data after click show more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First i want only 1 blog-block will show up and a show more. 
when i click show more it will show 1 more blog-block and if click show more again it will show 1 more blog-block again. and after all of blog-block show up, the show-more button will hidden. can you guys please help me

```
<!--  BLOG BLOCK 1  -->
<div class="blog-block">
    <img class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" src="images/blog-images/big-images/blog1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blog-details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <a href="blog_single.html">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</a>
        <p class="mini">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>

        <!--  BLOG INFO  -->
        <div class="blog-info">
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Admin</strong>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Photography</strong>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Comments</strong>
            </a>
            <span class="fa fa-comment">10</span>
        </div>
        <!--  //BLOG INFO  -->
    </div>

    <!--  BLOG DATE  -->
    <div class="date">
        <span class="day">25</span>
        <span class="month">nov</span>
    </div>       
    <!--  //BLOG DATE  -->                     
</div>  
<!--  //BLOG BLOCK 1  --> 

<!--  BLOG BLOCK 2  -->
<div class="blog-block">
    <img class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" src="images/blog-images/big-images/blog2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blog-details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <a href="#">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</a>
        <p class="mini">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>

        <!--  BLOG INFO  -->
        <div class="blog-info">
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Admin</strong>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Photography</strong>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Comments</strong>
            </a>
            <span class="fa fa-comment">10</span>
        </div>
        <!--  //BLOG INFO  -->
    </div>

    <!--  BLOG DATE  -->
    <div class="date">
        <span class="day">25</span>
        <span class="month">nov</span>
    </div>       
    <!--  //BLOG DATE  -->                     
</div>  
<!--  //BLOG BLOCK 2  --> 

<!--  BLOG BLOCK 3  -->
<div class="blog-block">
    <img class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" src="images/blog-images/big-images/blog3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blog-details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <a href="#">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</a>
        <p class="mini">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>

        <!--  BLOG INFO  -->
        <div class="blog-info">
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Admin</strong>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Photography</strong>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <strong>Comments</strong>
            </a>
            <span class="fa fa-comment">10</span>
        </div>
        <!--  //BLOG INFO  -->
    </div>

    <!--  BLOG DATE  -->
    <div class="date">
        <span class="day">25</span>
        <span class="month">nov</span>
    </div>       
    <!--  //BLOG DATE  -->                     
</div>  
<!--  //BLOG BLOCK 3  --> 

<!--  SHOW MORE BLOGS  -->
<div class="show-more">load more posts</div>
<!--  //SHOW MORE BLOGS  -->
<script>
    $('.show-more').on('click', function(){
        var mymore = '';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default hide all the `blog-block` elements except the first block  by adding `hide` class. and on click event remove `hide` class from `blog-block` elements.you can check working code here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--  BLOG BLOCK 1  -->
  <div class="blog-block">
    <img class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" src="images/blog-images/big-images/blog1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blog-details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <a href="blog_single.html">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</a>
      <p class="mini">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>

      <!--  BLOG INFO  -->
      <div class="blog-info">
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Admin</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Photography</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Comments</strong>
        </a>
        <span class="fa fa-comment">10</span>
      </div>
      <!--  //BLOG INFO  -->
    </div>

    <!--  BLOG DATE  -->
    <div class="date">
      <span class="day">25</span>
      <span class="month">nov</span>
    </div>
    <!--  //BLOG DATE  -->
  </div>
  <!--  //BLOG BLOCK 1  -->

  <!--  BLOG BLOCK 2  -->
  <div class="blog-block hide">
    <img class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" src="images/blog-images/big-images/blog2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blog-details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <a href="#">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</a>
      <p class="mini">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>

      <!--  BLOG INFO  -->
      <div class="blog-info">
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Admin</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Photography</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Comments</strong>
        </a>
        <span class="fa fa-comment">10</span>
      </div>
      <!--  //BLOG INFO  -->
    </div>

    <!--  BLOG DATE  -->
    <div class="date">
      <span class="day">25</span>
      <span class="month">nov</span>
    </div>
    <!--  //BLOG DATE  -->
  </div>
  <!--  //BLOG BLOCK 2  -->

  <!--  BLOG BLOCK 3  -->
  <div class="blog-block hide">
    <img class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" src="images/blog-images/big-images/blog3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blog-details col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <a href="#">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error.</a>
      <p class="mini">A popular Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>

      <!--  BLOG INFO  -->
      <div class="blog-info">
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Admin</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Photography</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <strong>Comments</strong>
        </a>
        <span class="fa fa-comment">10</span>
      </div>
      <!--  //BLOG INFO  -->
    </div>

    <!--  BLOG DATE  -->
    <div class="date">
      <span class="day">25</span>
      <span class="month">nov</span>
    </div>
    <!--  //BLOG DATE  -->
  </div>
  <!--  //BLOG BLOCK 3  -->

  <!--  SHOW MORE BLOGS  -->
  <div class="show-more">load more posts</div>
  <!--  //SHOW MORE BLOGS  -->
  <script>
    $('.show-more').on('click', function() {
      $('.blog-block.hide:lt(1)').removeClass('hide');
      if ($('.blog-block.hide').length == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: forgot to all `$(this).hide();` at last in click event.check the updated link

Comment: but i dont want it show all when show more clicked. i want it show 1 by 1

Comment: it is still show the rest of the hide class sir. the condition is show more will show 1 class bog-block each time we click it

Comment: its work nicely sir, but i just thinking about long term after the project go online.it will have a bunch of blog and i have to set to bigger default. example 5 data show for first and when i click show more it will show 5 more data?

Comment: if you want to display new 5 posts then use `$('.blog-block.hide:lt(5)).removeClass('hide');` lt(5) can be any number you desire.just inserted the snippet in answer.checkit

Comment: ill make it here sir can you see this https://jsbin.com/qivebihoze/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104742/discussion-between-pavan-teja-and-vandi).